# PySpark - Cast Long Epoch (in Milliseconds) to TimestampType with Native Spark Functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I'm using the PySpark library to read JSON files, process the data, and write back to parquet files.

The incoming data has a date field measured from the epoch in milliseconds.  E.g., `1541106106796` represents: `Thursday, November 1, 2018 9:01:46.796 PM`.

A valid solution uses the Python `datetime` library:

```
def format_datetime(ts):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(ts/1000.0)

...
get_timestamp = udf(lambda x: format_datetime(int(x)),TimestampType())
df = df.withColumn("timestamp", get_timestamp(df.ts))
```

Is there a solution that only uses native Spark functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **`from_unixtime`** and extract **milliseconds** from timestamp then add at the end, finally cast to **`timestamp`** type.

```
df.show()
#+-------------+
#|           ts|
#+-------------+
#|1541106106796|
#+-------------+

df.withColumn("ts1",expr('concat_ws(".",from_unixtime(substring(ts,1,length(ts)-3),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),substring(ts,length(ts)-2,length(ts)))').cast("timestamp")).\
show(10,False)
#+-------------+-----------------------+
#|ts           |ts1                    |
#+-------------+-----------------------+
#|1541106106796|2018-11-01 16:01:46.796|
#+-------------+-----------------------+
```

To create **`unixtime`** use `unix_timestamp` and `regexp_extract` functions.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------------------+
#|sample                                   |
#+-----------------------------------------+
#|Thursday, November 1, 2018 9:01:46.796 PM|
#+-----------------------------------------+

df.withColumn("ts",concat_ws('',unix_timestamp(col("sample"),"E, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a"),regexp_extract(col("sample"),"\\.(.*)\\s+",1))).\
show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
#|sample                                   |ts           |
#+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
#|Thursday, November 1, 2018 9:01:46.796 PM|1541124106796|
#+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
```